# how to execute ls>file.txt using execvp system call

Tags: exec, ls, execvp

how to execute ls>file.txt using execvp system call? I am trying to execute different commands using execvp system call. I want to know how to pass ls>file.txt to execvp

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that you must check for your own if command contains < or > and would have to redirect input and output using dup2 system call and then simply run 'ls' using execvp